# parallax like effect on span tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some bootstrap glyphicons used in my banner.

What I am looking for is to move the icons left or right as per mouse moves within my banner.

Something like this 
"http://stephband.info/jparallax/".

I tried using this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#banner .sl-slide').mousemove(function(e){
        var x = (e.pageX * -1 / 6);
        $('.flyInLeft').css('left',(0-(x*.25))+'px');
    });   
});
```

but when I move mouse, all elements get stick to left and move there.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Can you give us a jsfiddle or your html and css codes?

Comment: Just a guess, but I suspect you need `position:relative` css on the parent element if you are manipulating `left`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyones effort, but I just found my solution.

Her's the code I was looking for.

```
    $('#banner .sl-slide').mousemove(function(e){
        var x = (e.pageX * -1 / 6);
        var y = (e.pageY * -1 / 6);

        $('.flyInLeft').css('marginLeft',(0-(x*.25))+'px');
        $('.flyInRight').css('marginRight',(0-(x*.25))+'px');
        $('.flyInLeft, .flyInRight').css('marginTop',-(0-(y*.25))+'px');

    });   

    $('.banner').mouseleave(function(e){
        $('.flyInLeft, .flyInRight').animate({'margin': 0}, 1000);
    });
```